# Seaborn distplot: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, seaborn

I have been tampering with this script for some time now and cannot seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

The script:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import glob

# Load data set
dataset = { 1:{"Oxy":[], "De-oxy":[]}, 2:{"Oxy":[], "De-oxy":[]}, 3:{"Oxy":[], "De-oxy":[]}, 4:{"Oxy":[], "De-oxy":[]},
            5:{"Oxy":[], "De-oxy":[]}, 6:{"Oxy":[], "De-oxy":[]}, 7:{"Oxy":[], "De-oxy":[]}, 8:{"Oxy":[], "De-oxy":[]}, 9:{"Oxy":[], "De-oxy":[]}, 10:{"Oxy":[], "De-oxy":[]}, 
            11:{"Oxy":[], "De-oxy":[]}, 12:{"Oxy":[], "De-oxy":[]}, 13:{"Oxy":[], "De-oxy":[]}, 14:{"Oxy":[], "De-oxy":[]}, 
            15:{"Oxy":[], "De-oxy":[]}, 16:{"Oxy":[], "De-oxy":[]}, 17:{"Oxy":[], "De-oxy":[]}, 18:{"Oxy":[], "De-oxy":[]}, 19:{"Oxy":[], "De-oxy":[]}, 20:{"Oxy":[], "De-oxy":[]}, 
            21:{"Oxy":[], "De-oxy":[]}, 22:{"Oxy":[], "De-oxy":[]}, 23:{"Oxy":[], "De-oxy":[]}, 24:{"Oxy":[], "De-oxy":[]}, 25:{"Oxy":[], "De-oxy":[]}, 26:{"Oxy":[], "De-oxy":[]}, 27:{"Oxy":[], "De-oxy":[]}, 28:{"Oxy":[], "De-oxy":[]}, 29:{"Oxy":[], "De-oxy":[]}, 30:{"Oxy":[], "De-oxy":[]}}


oxy_files = glob.glob("/Users/gabagaba/Documents/MATLAB/Subject-output/Oxy/*.txt")
deoxy_files = glob.glob("/Users/gabagaba/Documents/MATLAB/Subject-output/DeOxy/*.txt")

for item in sorted(oxy_files): # Put all oxy readings in dataset_oxy
    with open(item) as file:
        content = ""
        for line in file:
            content = content + line.replace("\n", ",")
        items = content.split(',')

        count = 1
        for i in items:
            if ( count < 31 ):
                dataset[count]['Oxy'].append(i)
            else:
                pass
            count += 1

for item in sorted(deoxy_files): # Put all de-oxy readings in dataset_deoxy
    with open(item) as file:
        content = ""
        for line in file:
            content = content + line.replace("\n", ",")
        items = content.split(',')

        count = 1
        for i in items:
            if ( count < 31 ):
                dataset[count]['De-oxy'].append(i)
            else:
                pass
            count += 1

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (15,10))
ax = plt.gca()
j = 1

for a in sorted(dataset.keys()):
    val = pd.DataFrame({'Oxy': dataset[a]['Oxy'], 'De-oxy': dataset[a]['De-oxy']})
    subax = plt.subplot(5,6,j)

    try:
        sns.distplot(val, bins=29, hist=True, kde=True, rug=True,
                     ax = subax, color = 'k', norm_hist = True) # This distplot function generates the error from the dataframe input.

    except Exception as Ex:
        print Ex

    subax.set_title("Sensor " + str(a))
    subax.set_xlim(-5,5)

    j += 1

plt.subplots_adjust(left = 0.06, right = 0.99, bottom = 0.07,
                    top = 0.92, wspace = 0.14, hspace = 0.6) 

fig.text(0.5, 0.02, 'De-oxy', ha ='center', fontsize = 15)
fig.text(0.02, 0.5, 'Oxy', ha ='center', 
         rotation='vertical', fontsize = 15) 

plt.show()
```

The val data frame looks something like:

```
         De-oxy          Oxy
0    0.00006010   0.00004332
1    0.00001508  -0.00039567
2    0.00002082  -0.00018257
3    0.00001455  -0.00014494
4    0.00003703  -0.00007764
5    0.00001842  -0.00030163
6    0.00006357  -0.00024539
7    0.00006357  -0.00024539
8   -0.00000054  -0.00018082
9    0.00001561   0.00000669
10   0.00010251  -0.00017378
11   0.00004183  -0.00022999
12  -0.00001308   0.00000502
13   0.00002442  -0.00007114
14   0.00000000   0.00000000
15  -0.00001547   0.00007255
16  -0.00000693   0.00000565
17  -0.00002355   0.00007807
18   0.00000000   0.00000000
19  -0.00000884   0.00006787
20   0.00001404  -0.00010094
21   0.00009296  -0.00035937
22   0.00000000   0.00000000
23   0.00000825  -0.00006484
24   0.00001220  -0.00012597
25  -0.00002296   0.00006205
26   0.00003026  -0.00012464
27   0.00000340  -0.00002748
28   0.00000149   0.00170630
```

I put in some comments on where I think it goes wrong. So the actual question here is: What am I missing when the data is converted into the plot that it errors with the message from the title?

The goal is to get a plot for every key (sensor #) in the dataset with the oxy values on the x axis and de-oxy on the y axis.

Edit:
As requested a traceback:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testing.py", line 75, in <module>
    ax = subax, norm_hist = True) 
  File "/Users/gabagaba/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/seaborn/distributions.py", line 192, in distplot
    line, = ax.plot(a.mean(), 0)
  File "/Users/gabagaba/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 82, in _mean
    ret = ret / rcount
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: can you give a stack trace?

Comment: Could it be from: `i = "0"`? Hmm, but also `dataset[][]` lists are filled with `string` representations of `float`s.

Comment: Can you edit the post to include the error you're getting?

Comment: @Tim: The exact error is: "unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'"

Comment: @CristiFati Unfortunately this did not solve it.. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: `print` all the arguments passed to `sns.distplot` (especially the array ones), and most likely there will be some stringified numbers (surrounded by simple or double quotes). I imagine that when plotting a series some internal operations (like *scaling*) are performed, and those typically use numeric factors.

Comment: The reason this fails is as indicated by @CristiFati: You are trying to plot the mean of some strings. This operation is not defined, you can only calculate the mean of an array of numbers, not strings. Ignoring the above comment and saying that it did not solve the issue is not helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I wasn't ignoring CristiFati's answer. The new comment CristiFati had posted I have not yet been able to verify. The first comment was about a part of the code which I removed entirely as it was not needed. I will check and see where I will get with your helpful replies.

Answer (score 2):

Following @CristiFati's advice I double checked all data input and ended up converting all input to floats. This fixed the issue.

The adapted code is:

```
dataset[count]['Oxy'].append(float(i))
```

This was also done for the de-oxy input.